# jQuery .animate animates the div but not the image inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

When I animate a div using jQuery, the div gets bigger, but the picture inside of it stays the same size.

How to I make the div, as well as the image inside of it, get bigger but remain to scale?

Do I actually have to address everything that is in the stylesheet, in the .animate() method? Not just width and height? If so, how do I manipulate the `url("someImage.jpg")` that is in the stylesheet.

Here is some sample code that illustrates what I am talking about:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <style type="text/css">
            #one { /* Second info block */
                float: right;
                height: 350px;
                width: 275px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-top: 35px;
                margin-right: 175px;  
                background: url(http://magazine8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/most-beautiful-flowers.jpg) no-repeat;
                background-size: 300px;
                background-position: center; 
            }
        </style>        
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>        
        <div id="one"></div>    
        <script>        
            $("#one").click(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: "500px",
                    height: "700px",
                }, 1000);
            });        
        </script>        
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Add various selectors to your animation... e.g. `$("#one, #one > img")`

Comment: Change the background-size in animate. You just change the div size. That does not effect the background image. You set an absolute size of the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

Just increase your `background-size: xx px;` or `(backgroundSize:"xx px")` along width & height changes.

```js
$("#one").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "500px",
    height: "700px",
    backgroundSize: "500px",
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#one {
  /* Second info block */
  float: right;
  height: 350px;
  width: 275px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 175px;
  background: url(http://magazine8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/most-beautiful-flowers.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
```

> Note : I have just randomly added 500px, change as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You've set a fixed background size of 300px so it's not going to change whatever size the containing div is. Try this in your CSS:

```
#one {
     /* your styles */
     background: url('http://magazine8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/most-beautiful-flowers.jpg') no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     background-position: 
}
```

Setting the background size to `contain` will make the image always as large as possible to fill the container, while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

**Edit**

Since your preferred scale isn't 100%, you can use a percentage size. About 110% is what you're looking for to keep the same scale.

```
background-size: 110%;
```

**MDN**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Or he can change the background-size to another value. I am not sure if he wants to use contain for the size of the background image.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realize at first that he wants to make it slightly bigger than the containing `<div>`. How about `background-size: 110%;`?